PySpark app returns "NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/util/Logging"
I had this error:
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o59.start.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/util/Logging
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1022)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource.getTable(DefaultSource.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource.inferSchema(DefaultSource.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Utils$.getTableFromProvider(DataSourceV2Utils.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.startInternal(DataStreamWriter.scala:396)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:249)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.util.Logging
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
        ... 26 more


When running this python script:
import logging

from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType


def create_keyspace(session):
    session.execute("""
        CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS spark_streams
        WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'};
    """)

    print("Keyspace created successfully!")


def create_table(session):
    session.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS spark_streams.created_users (
        id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
        first_name TEXT,
        last_name TEXT,
        gender TEXT,
        address TEXT,
        post_code TEXT,
        email TEXT,
        username TEXT,
        registered_date TEXT,
        phone TEXT,
        picture TEXT);
    """)

    print("Table created successfully!")


def insert_data(session, **kwargs):
    print("inserting data...")

    user_id = kwargs.get('id')
    first_name = kwargs.get('first_name')
    last_name = kwargs.get('last_name')
    gender = kwargs.get('gender')
    address = kwargs.get('address')
    postcode = kwargs.get('post_code')
    email = kwargs.get('email')
    username = kwargs.get('username')
    dob = kwargs.get('dob')
    registered_date = kwargs.get('registered_date')
    phone = kwargs.get('phone')
    picture = kwargs.get('picture')

    try:
        session.execute("""
            INSERT INTO spark_streams.created_users(id, first_name, last_name, gender, address, 
                post_code, email, username, dob, registered_date, phone, picture)
                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
        """, (user_id, first_name, last_name, gender, address,
              postcode, email, username, dob, registered_date, phone, picture))
        logging.info(f"Data inserted for {first_name} {last_name}")

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'could not insert data due to {e}')


def create_spark_connection():
    s_conn = None

    try:
        s_conn = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName('SparkDataStreaming') \
            .config('spark.jars.packages', "com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.4.1,"
                                           "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.4.1,"
                                            "org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients:2.3.1") \
            .config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', 'localhost') \
            .getOrCreate()

        s_conn.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
        logging.info("Spark connection created successfully!")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Couldn't create the spark session due to exception {e}")

    return s_conn


def connect_to_kafka(spark_conn):
    spark_df = None
    try:
        spark_df = spark_conn.readStream \
            .format('kafka') \
            .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', 'localhost:9092') \
            .option('subscribe', 'users_created') \
            .option('startingOffsets', 'earliest') \
            .load()
        logging.info("kafka dataframe created successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warning(f"kafka dataframe could not be created because: {e}")

    return spark_df


def create_cassandra_connection():
    try:
        # connecting to the cassandra cluster
        cluster = Cluster(['localhost'])

        cas_session = cluster.connect()

        return cas_session
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Could not create cassandra connection due to {e}")
        return None


def create_selection_df_from_kafka(spark_df):
    schema = StructType([
        StructField("id", StringType(), False),
        StructField("first_name", StringType(), False),
        StructField("last_name", StringType(), False),
        StructField("gender", StringType(), False),
        StructField("address", StringType(), False),
        StructField("post_code", StringType(), False),
        StructField("email", StringType(), False),
        StructField("username", StringType(), False),
        StructField("registered_date", StringType(), False),
        StructField("phone", StringType(), False),
        StructField("picture", StringType(), False)
    ])

    sel = spark_df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
        .select(from_json(col('value'), schema).alias('data')).select("data.*")
    print(sel)

    return sel


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create spark connection
    spark_conn = create_spark_connection()

    if spark_conn is not None:
        # connect to kafka with spark connection
        spark_df = connect_to_kafka(spark_conn)
        selection_df = create_selection_df_from_kafka(spark_df)
        session = create_cassandra_connection()

        if session is not None:
            create_keyspace(session)
            create_table(session)

            logging.info("Streaming is being started...")

            streaming_query = (selection_df.writeStream.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                               .option('checkpointLocation', '/tmp/checkpoint')
                               .option('keyspace', 'spark_streams')
                               .option('table', 'created_users')
                               .start())

            streaming_query.awaitTermination()

Its weird because I already pasted the spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.4.1.jar into .venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/jars. Maybe I did not install it the correct way so there are missing dependencies or something like that.
Is there any dependency that I'm missing?
Should I install this jar any other way?
Thank you.

were you able to fix the error? I was also doing the same project and got the same errors as yours.
I'd love to know how you fixed it.

I agree with your assessment that there are dependencies missing from your build.
Instead of building with the connector JAR, I suggest specifying the package coordinates for the Spark Cassandra connector with the --packages option so that all dependencies are included in your app.
For example, try launching a PySpark shell with:
$ bin/pyspark \
  --master <spark_master_url> \
  --spark.cassandra.connection.host=cassandra_host_ip \
  --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.4.1
  --conf spark.sql.extensions=com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions

Note that I'm assuming you're connecting from a Spark 3.4 cluster.
For additional info, see the PySpark page in the Spark Cassandra connector docs. Cheers!

Glad to help. I'd be very interested to know how you resolve it in the end. Cheers!
